# Admin Dashboard page “Last Orders” section which is showing wrong order Total value

Tags: magento2.3

I have Magento 2.3.4, I have set all pricing as Including Tax, I have added pricing in products Including Tax, everything is works fine, just one issue is in Admin Dashboard page “Last Orders” section which is showing wrong order Total value. Its showing only base vale (Without Tax, Without Shipping etc…) but I want to show its same value as showing Sales -> Orders listing page. I have set 10% TAX.

Here I have attached both shots for Orders listing and Dashboard:

159 = 144.55 + 14.45 (Tax)
409 = 371.82 + 37.18 (Tax)
449 = 408.18 + 40.82 (Tax)
78.90 = 62.73 + 6.27 (Tax) + 9.90 (Shipping)
549 = 499.09 + 49.91 (Tax)

So I want to show final total on dashboard orders. See attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you find where this configured?